# Bochner theorem for (non-abelian) discrete groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, c-star-algebras, pontrjagin-duality

I am interested in Pontryagin duality-like theories for discrete groups, more particularly, whether an analogue to [Bochner's theorem for abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem) exists in the discrete non-finite and non-abelian setting.

I have seen the paper "[Lubotzky - Tannaka duality for discrete groups](https://doi.org/10.2307/2374092)" and know about the Hopf-algebra generalizations of the Pontryagin dual but neither reference a Bochner's theorem, so my question is:

Is there a duality theory for a discrete (amenable) group and an analogue of Bochner's theorem in such a theory?

Comment: Perhaps related (in duality): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409642/bochner-style-theorem-for-so3